# N-Qubit Hadamard vs Quantum Fourier Transform

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, hadamard, simons-algorithm

Both Simon's algorithm and the algorithm for period finding begin by placing qubits in the equal superposition state, but Simon's algorithm uses the n-qubit Hadamard $H^{\otimes n}$ while the period finding algorithm uses the quantum Fourier transform. My understanding is both QFT and  the n-qubit Hadamard perform the same operation on the $|00...0\rangle$ state, creating the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}|x\rangle$ state. I'm reading this from the [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/simon.html).

When the result is the same, why do the two algorithms use different ways to achieve the equal superposition? More generally, when would one use the n-qubit Hadamard, and when would one use the QFT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out correctly, both $H^{\otimes n}$ and QFT applied on input state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ return state

$$
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n}|i\rangle.
$$

There is no special reason why $n$ qubit Hadamard gate cannot replace QFT for $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ input. Maybe, an author of article about Simon's algorithm wanted to be more precise.

**Overall, it does not matter which approach you use. Both return same result for $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ input.**

**EDIT** (based on *DaftWullie* comment): However, in practice $n$ qubits Hadamard is prefered as it is very simple circuit in comparison with QFT.

Comment: But the hadamard transform is easier to implement than the Fourier, so for the initialisation step, you would always use the hadamard transform.

Comment: @DaftWullie: Yes, absolutely agree in practice. However, the question was if there is any difference from theoretical point of view (at least, I understood it in this way).

Comment: well, the last part was "when would one use..."

Comment: @DaftWullie: Right, I edited the answer accordingly.